# User account registration using Craft 3

Tags: craft3, users, craft-features, user-groups, current-user

I wanted to build a commerce website using Craft 3. And I wanted to create parent registration form so each parent will have an account to use on the site. Then after they sign in I want them to be able to add their children.

Is this possible to do using Craft 3. The only thing I found is user registration form on the documentation.

If there is a blog or documentation that shows how to integrate this feature using Craft 3 or is there anything I missed so far.

Comment: You'll need a custom Controller for that task if you don't want to have to deal with heavy security issues. Nearly everything in Craft is doable with a little bit customization.

Comment: Do I need the Pro version for user account features? Is that a must to have?

Comment: Yes you need a pro license